# Win10 "Connection properties" changes from "Certificate" to "Smart card" when I try to connect to IKEv2 VPN server

Tags: windows-10, vpn, strongswan

I try to connect to  Debian Strong Swan VPN server from Windows 10. I create CA certificate on Debian server and import the root certificate to Windows "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".
Next I configure the VPN on Windows with these steps:

- Launch Control Panel,
- Navigate to the 'Network and Sharing Center'.
- Click on 'Set up a new connection or network'
- Select 'Connect to a workplace'
- Select Use my Internet connection (VPN)

.

Then enter the VPN server details:

- Server IP address
- select "IKEv2" as VPN type
- select "Certificate'  as "Type of sign-in info"

Then I press **"Save"** button.

Yet when I then select  "Advanced options' of my VPN,  "Type of sign-in info" in "Connection properties" changes from "Certificate" to "Smart card" and when I try to connect to VPN server, Windows requests me to "Insert a smart card" that I don't have  and I can not connect to VPN.
How to fix this?

**Update:**

Now, when I put Debian Strong Swan CA certificate to Windows 10 Personal certificates, I get the same certificate in two locations: in Personal and in Trusted Root Certification, as follows :

```
Console Root/Certificates(Local Computer)/Personal/Certificates

  Issued To: VPN root CA 
  Issued By: VPN root CA 
  Expiration Date: 1/8/2034
  Intended Purposes: <All>

Console Root/Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates

  Issued To: VPN root CA 
  Issued By: VPN root CA 
  Expiration Date: 1/8/2034
  Inteded Purposes: <All>
```

As a result, when trying to connect to Strong Swan VPN I get:

```
Policy match error
```

What may be wrong in this case?

Comment: Where is your user certificate and its private key? Maybe your VPN client can't find your user cert and the matching private key, so it's falling back to expecting those things to be on a smart card.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my question update.

Comment: Your update talks about a **CA cert**, but I wasn't asking about a CA cert. I was asking about a **user cert** and the **user private key** that corresponds to the user cert.

Comment: I configure Strongswan VPN and Windows client according to this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-18-04-2
In this guide  user cert and the user private key are not used for VPN configuration.

Comment: That guide does **not** tell you to switch the "Type of sign-in info" to "Certificate", so that seems to be where you got off-track. You should have left it on the username/password setting if you wanted to use a username and password to connect. If you set it to Certificate, you will need to generate a user certificate (along with the corresponding user private key), and install those things, but that can be a little complicated and the instructions you were following don't seem to cover those procedures.

Comment: With "IKEv2" as VPN type, and when I have the same Debian Strong Swan CA certificate both in Personal and in Trusted Root Certification locations on Windows, and when I set username/password  login, it then returns back to Certificate login when I next time  use 'advanced option' button  to see login type. The problem remains.

Comment: What kind of client authentication have you configured your VPN server to accept or expect? You might want to look at whether you set up your server's `/etc/ipsec.conf` and `/etc/ipsec.secrets` exactly like your tutorial was telling you to. Maybe you accidentally set up your server to expect cert-based client authentication, or you failed to set it up with a username/password credential to look for, so its falling back to ask for certificate-based auth.